# Not able to add the screenshot to the extent report in Cucumber

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, cucumber-junit, extentreports

> I am unable to add the screenshot of failed case to the extent report in Cucumber (java).

```
//Runner class to generate extent report
@AfterClass
public static void Report() {

    Reporter.loadXMLConfig(new File("/Users/chetan/Documents/workspace/Packages/extent-config.xml"));
    Properties p = new Properties();
    p.list(System.out);

}

//Main class contains step definitions
@After("@browser")
public void teardown(WebDriver driver, Scenario scenario, String screenshotName) throws IOException {
    if (scenario.isFailed()) {
        final byte[] screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
        scenario.embed(screenshot, "image/png");

        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: @Guy I am able to generate the extent report, But i wasn't able to add the screenshot for the failed cases. I am using Cucumber Framework. Kindly Help me

Comment: You need to give more details. Where is the problem? what **exactly** is the problem? you have errors? *I am unable to add the screenshot* is not very helpful description of the problem.

Comment: @Guy I doesn't have any errors My above mentioned code is capturing screenshot and saving in a specified folder under my project. But I could not be able to add it  to the extent report.

Comment: @NarendraChetan Please share your trial code which Report objects.

Comment: @IshitaShah, I didn't get u what u are asking exactly

Comment: You need to share your code, where you have defined Report object.

Comment: @IshitaShah   RunWith(Cucumber.class)

CucumberOptions(features={"Features/BookingPackage.feature"},
     glue={"Packages_Scripts"},
      plugin={"com.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter:/Users/chetan/Documents/workspace/Packages/Report/Report.html"}
      )
public class Book_Package_Runner {
 
 AfterClass
 public static void Report() 
 {
  
  Reporter.loadXMLConfig(new File("/Users/chetan/Documents/workspace/Packages/extent-config.xml"));
  Properties p=new Properties();
  p.list(System.out);
  
 }

Comment: @IshitaShahMy code in the other class with step definitions .       

public class Book_Package {
  After("@Package_Booking")
 public void teardown() throws IOException
 {
  if(scenario.isFailed())
  {
   scenario.embed(((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES),"image/png");
   
   final byte[] screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
   scenario.embed(screenshot, "image/png");
    
   driver.quit();
  }
 }
 
 Given
 When
 When
 When
 Then
 Then
  

 
}

Answer (score 1):

You need to define Extent Report Object at class Level or wherever you like. And then you can use it on Failure.

- For the Report location: **Create New Folder with name Report** in your project directory at root location
- For the Screenshot location: **Create New Folder with name Screenshots** in your project directory at root location

**Code:**

```
//Report Initialization
ExtentHtmlReporter htmlreport = new ExtentHtmlReporter(".\\Report\\Extent Report with Screenshot.html");
ExtentReports reports = new ExtentReports();
reports.attachReporter(htmlreport);
ExtentTest testlog;

//Capture and save screenshot
File screen = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(screen);
File filetest = Paths.get(".").toAbsolutePath().normalize().toFile();
ImageIO.write(img, "png", new File(filetest + "\\Screenshots\\" + "Test.png"));

//Log Screenshot in Report
testlog.info("Details of " + "Test screenshot", MediaEntityBuilder
                .createScreenCaptureFromPath(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\Screenshots\\" + "Test.png").build());

//Flush Report-Mandatory, Else report will not generate.  
reports.flush();
```

**You can refer my example from Github ([Click here](https://github.com/ishah09/ExtentReport-3.1.5/blob/master/src/test/java/extentReportWithTestNG/ExceptionWithFailureScreenshot.java)), for ease of Use.**

Comment: I think your code is in Testng. How it will works for cucumber? I am using cucumber framework kindly help me for the same.

Comment: Code is all about to take reference for Extent Report. Its depend on you, how you use it for Cucumber.

Comment: now i was able to capture the screen shot with the code shared by u, It is saving in a folder but not adding to the Extent report

Comment: This is working code. You may have issue with your code. You need to check it.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't add the screenshot to the report

```
ExtentTest test = extent.createTest("TestName");
test.fail("details").addScreenCaptureFromPath("pathToScreenshot");
// or
test.fail("details", MediaEntityBuilder.createScreenCaptureFromPath("pathToScreenshot").build());
```

Comment: can u please suggest me where i need to add the given code. That would be helpful a lot for me. Sorry for the inconvenience caused I am a learner to the extent reports so getting a lot of doubts.

Comment: @NarendraChetan Use `extent.createTest` before the test, say in `@AfterClass` (or any other similar place). The other lines are to add the image to the log, use them wherever you want to write to the log.

Comment: i am also getting error at "extent" i could not able to resolve it

Comment: @NarendraChetan`extent` is the `ExtentReporter`, `ExtentReporter extent = new ExtentReports();`.

Comment: I tried with the code shared by u and what the problem i am facing is "ExtentReporter extent = new ExtentReports();" It is asking to add cast to it. Can u help me.. and also ".createTest" is asking add cast to extent

Answer (score 0):

This is question for extent reports cucumber adapter but answers are for extent reports.
Please open report and see in console the link to the screenshot path and check if images are there.

It is known issue that extent adapters save screenshots in test-output folder for some reason, you may need to do put screenshot folder in extent.properties or use SystemSet

The problem was apparently solved in new snapshot but I have to check that